# My Antd form not set value after use setFieldsValue in Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, antd, react-testing-library

I'm using testing-library/react-hooks lib with renderHook, my problem is that I'm not able to set a value for my antd form using setFieldsValue, it's not setting the value, what's missing?

this is my Report.service.test.tsx:

```
it("user can export report with successfully", async () => {
    const formExportReportUserHook = renderHook(() => Form.useForm());
    const formReport = formExportReportUserHook.result.current[0];

    formReport.setFieldsValue({
      rangePicker: [dayjs(), dayjs()],
    });

    await onConfirmExportReport({
      formReport: formReport,
      message,
    });
  });
});
```

and my Report.service.tsx

```
export const onConfirmExportReport = async ({
  formReport,
  message,
}: IExportReport) => {
  try {
    const { rangePicker }: IReport = await formReport.validateFields();
    const bodyRequest: IReportRequest = {
      initialEventTime: rangePicker[0].format("MM-DD-YYYY"),
      finalEventTime: rangePicker[1].format("MM-DD-YYYY"),
      ...
```

My const rangePicker is undefined, it doesn't find the rangePicker value, set in Report.service.test
But if I do it like this in the service

```
const getRangePicker= formReport.getFieldValue("rangePicker");
```

It will return the value.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to make some changes to Report-service.tsx and it worked

```
 export const onConfirmExportReport = async ({
      formReport,
      message,
    }: IExportReport) => {
      try {
        await formReport.validateFields();
        const rangePicker = formReport.getFieldValue("rangePicker");
        const bodyRequest: IReportRequest = {
          initialEventTime: rangePicker[0].format("MM-DD-YYYY"),
          finalEventTime: rangePicker[1].format("MM-DD-YYYY"),
    ...
```